# Special characters in filename leads to starting virus executable

Tags: virus, vulnerability, torrent, code-execution

So I've just downloaded torrent with one file in it - the formal name of file should  be "123.avi.exe" (which is typical for viruses and trojans). Now, interesting thing is that name is encoded in UTF16-LE as following bytes:

```
FFFE3100320033002E002D202E202D202E206900760061002E00650078006500
```

which gives us strange, partially reversed over ".exe" text (try to move cursor left-to-right and you will be surprised):

```
123.‭‮‭‮iva.exe
```

But the bad part of all - is that utorrent showing non-suspicious ".avi" extension while when you double click it in GUI - it goes as as ".exe" and program runs.

You can test it yourself by creating dummy file with the name I wrote above. One more interesting thing - Total Commander prevents executing such file if it's name contains these special characters.

P.S. I've started similar [thread](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/105938-partially-showed-filename-leads-to-starting-virus-executable) on uTorrent tracker (not yet approved by moderator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is the [right-to-left override character](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2011/09/right-to-left-override-aids-email-attacks/). Languages such as Arabic write right-to-left instead of left-to-right. To embed such text in a string, you can switch the direction of the text, and that can help in hiding the real extension.

```
helloworld.<RLO>cod.exe
```

will be displayed as

```
helloworld.exe.doc
```

because the part after the RLO character is reversed.